# How to check that the incoming JSON feed contains a single record or multiple?

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have to parse this JSON on iOS.

```
{
"log_by_dates": {
    "logs": [
        {
            "date": "Wednesday 5 December 2012",
            "exercises": "0",
            "workouts": "0",
            "log_entries": "0"
        },
        {
            "date": "Tuesday 4 December 2012",
            "exercises": "4",
            "workouts": "2",
            "log_entries": "7"
        }
    ]
 }
}
```

I have written following code to parse it;

```
NSArray *logs = [[(NSDictionary*)results objectForKey:@"log_by_dates"] objectForKey:@"logs"];
        for (NSDictionary *aLog in logs) {
            Log *newLog = [[Log alloc] initWithDate:[aLog objectForKey:@"date"]               withExercises:[aLog objectForKey:@"exercises"]
                                       withWorkouts:[aLog objectForKey:@"workouts"]];
            if (!data) {
               data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            }
```

But problem is that, sometimes I get the JSON value like this;

```
{

"log_by_dates": {
    "logs":
        {
            "date": "Wednesday 5 December 2012",
            "exercises": "0",
            "workouts": "0",
            "log_entries": "0"
        }
  }
}
```

Which makes my code to crash.

Please guide me, which if() else condition I use to check that whether the incoming JSON object contains multiple records of the single one before parsing so that I code write appropriate code to handle the dictionary or array.
Thanks,

Comment: How does it crash, whats the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your code like this.

```
NSArray *logs = [[(NSDictionary*)results objectForKey:@"log_by_dates"] objectForKey:@"logs"];
if([logs isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    for (NSDictionary *aLog in logs) {
        Log *newLog = [[Log alloc] initWithDate:[aLog objectForKey:@"date"]               withExercises:[aLog objectForKey:@"exercises"]
                                   withWorkouts:[aLog objectForKey:@"workouts"]];
        if (!data) {
            data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
    }
}
else if([logs isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    NSDictionary *aLog = (NSDictionary *)logs;
    Log *newLog = [[Log alloc] initWithDate:[aLog objectForKey:@"date"]               withExercises:[aLog objectForKey:@"exercises"]
                               withWorkouts:[aLog objectForKey:@"workouts"]];
    if (!data) {
        data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the condition like

```
if([[[(NSDictionary*)results objectForKey:@"log_by_dates"] objectForKey:@"logs"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
{
    // Do your Array Stuff Here
} else {
    // Do your Dictionary Stuff Here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert this before your `for` loop:

```c
if (![logs isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
{
    logs = [NSArray arrayWithObject:logs];
}
```